# php: extracting substring from the string by sub-substring

Tags: php, string, preg-match, substring, strpos

We have some string `$text="Here are some text. The word is inside of the second sentence.";`and `$word="word";`

How to get `$sentence="The word is inside of the second sentence";` - the first sentence that contains `" ".$word." "`

Of course some assumptions should be made. One of them is that all sentences are finished with `".\r\n"` or `"!\r\n"` or `". "` or `"! "`.

P.S. We are sure `strpos($text," ".$word." ")!==false`

Comment: have you tried regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text:

```
$txt = "word word word different. different word word word. word word word ending. word word word";
```

My word is 'different':

```
$word = "different";
```

Let us do a preg match:

```
$c=preg_match("/(\.|^)([^\.]*?".$word."[^\.]*(\.|$))/",$txt,$match);
```

If it is successful show the second group which holds the sentence:

```
if($c!==false and count($match) > 0 )
    echo( $match[2]) ;
```

This will return the first occurence. If you want all use preg_match_all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I would do is just use " ".$word." " instead of .$word. Thank you!

Comment: Ah sorry not thought about that - but it will be:
    <here i had a wrong regex>

Comment: Sorry:
$c=preg_match("/(!|\.|^)([^\.^!]*?".$word."[^\.^!]*(\.|$|!))/",$txt,$match); The same will probably go for other sentence endings, but if you can code a bit you probably noticed already when I have added the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
<?php

$text="Here are some text. The word is inside of the second sentence. And the word is also in this sentence!";
$word = 'word';


function getSentenceByWord($text, $word) {

    $sentences = preg_split('/(\.|\?|\!)(\s)/',$text);
    $matches = array();
    foreach($sentences as $sentence) {

        if (strpos($sentence,$word) !== false) {
            $matches[] = $sentence;
        }

    }

    return $matches;
}

print_r(getSentenceByWord($text, $word));
?>
```

returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => The word is inside of the second sentence
    [1] => And the word is also in this sentence!
)
```

Comment: The same if (strpos($sentence," ".$word." ") !== false), but it also works perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expressions, with a single delimiter, ".":

```
<?php
$text="Sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three. Sentence four.";

$word_pos = strpos($text, "Sentence");
$start = strrpos(substr($text, 0, $word_pos), ".");
$end = strpos(substr($text, $word_pos), ".");

$start = $start ? $start + 2 : 0;
$end = $end + $word_pos + 1 - $start;

$sentence = substr($text, $start, $end);

echo $sentence;
```

Comment: Assumes only . as the delimiter, would have to work with str_replace to allow for others such as ! and ?.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work for the word "some" ($start is undefined although it should be the first sentence).

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was some very sloppy testing (and coding!) on my part. Edited and tested with words ["Sentence", "one", "two", "three", "four"]. All that said, I'd go with a regular expression personally...